# CSS positioning - floating left and centered issue

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is a basic question to those of you who work in HTML and CSS regularly.

I have two pieces of text, both need to appear on the SAME line - one needs to be left aligned, and the other needs to be centered, regardless of how much text is in the left-aligned block (obviously while the length of the left-aligned text does not extend over the halfway mark).

To make this easier to understand and test, I have included a sample. In my sample, I have what I need, but on 2 lines instead of the same line.

Please repost the working sample if you find a solution.

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alignment Test</title>
    <style>
        body {background-color: #E6E6E6;}
        #reference {width: 100%;
                    border: solid 1px navy;}
        #half1 {width: 50%;
                text-align: right;
                border-right: dotted 1px navy}
        #container {width: 100%;
                    text-align: center;
                    border: solid 1px navy;}
        #floatLeft {float:left;
                    border: dotted 1px green;
                    background-color: #D0F5A9;}
        #centered {width: 100%;
                      border: dotted 1px red;
                      background-color: #F5F6CE;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="reference">
        <div id="half1">Middle of container -->&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="half2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="centered">This text should be centered
            <div id="floatLeft">This text should be left aligned</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align:center;position:relative">
    Centered
    <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0">Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Y.

That gave me the result I was looking for. The container's position had to be set (to relative) at which point the absolute position of the left content was then contained within it. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Y. Shoham's solution works. Here's another, which handles wrapping content more gracefully (does not allow overlap between center and left section), but which requires changing the order of items in the markup:

```
<div style="text-align: center; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="float: left; text-align: left;">left</div>
  centered
</div>
```

(The `text-align: left` may not make a difference, eg if there's no width specified and nothing inside has an inherent width, like an image.)

Comment: This also takes into consideration (in terms of width) the floated element when centering the text .. so the centered text will be centered in the remainder of the container div ..

Comment: That's true - and is exactly what i was trying to avoid. Perhaps I didn't word the question clearly, but I'd like the 'Centered' text to remain centered in the container irrespective of the remaining space...
If you copy my code from above and implement your solution, you get a single line but the 'Centered' text will not be central compared to the line above it demarking the middle of the container.